# Returning a PartialViewResult from another Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Right now I'm rewriting some code, but I also want to use existing code as a placeholder. I have a "Reference" controller that houses all of the new code and a "References" controller that houses the old code.

All I want to do is simply return a PartialViewResult from my old References controller from my Reference controller. I tried doing this:

```
public PartialViewResult ResolveView(int type)
{
    //Other code
    if (type == (int)ReferenceType.Participant) return ParticipantView();

    //return default partial view
    ...
}

//Called from ResolveView
private PartialViewResult ParticipantView()
{
    return RedirectToAction("ParticipantsView", "References");
}
```

Here's what I have for my old controller method:

```
public PartialViewResult ParticipantsView()
{
    var viewmodel = new ParticipantCreateViewModel
                            {
                                Participant = new ParticipantViewModel(),
                                Person = new ParticipantPersonViewModel(),
                                Types = ReferenceService.GetData<ParticipantType>(),
                            };
    return PartialView("_ParticipantsView");
}
```

I'm currently getting an error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult'`

What do I need to do to get it to return my PartialViewResult from my other controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method signature to return ActionResult

```
private ActionResult ParticipantsView()
{
 return RedirectToAction("ParticipantsView", "References");
}
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why... can you post the rest of the code that you are using?

Comment: Are you sure you changed the signature from `PartialViewResult` to `ActionResult` as Chadnu's code suggests?

Comment: I did on the private method I outlined in the question, yes. Chandu added an 's' at the end of Participant and before View on it.

Comment: I would not strongly type any of those, leave them all as ActionResult.